# Validation controls - set focus on specific anchor

Tags: asp.net

I using ASP.NET Validation Controls to validate fields on a form and I need to set the focus on a specific anchor within my page, but it keeps moving to the top of the page even though `SetFocusOnError` is set to **True**. I tried adding a `CustomValidator` with a `ClientValidationFunction` but it runs before validation hence moving back to the top of the page.

I also tried this:

[Set focus to validation summary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3473874/set-focus-to-validation-summary)

But the first link is no longer available and the second one just don't work (**That's why answers should be self contained!**).

Here are samples of my code:

```
    <asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary1" ClientIDMode="Static"
    runat="server" HeaderText="[custom message in my native language]"
    ValidationGroup="Valida" CssClass="msg_erro" />

    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="vldNome" runat="server"
    ControlToValidate="txtNome" ValidationGroup="Valida" Display="Dynamic"
    ErrorMessage="blah blah blah" SetFocusOnError="True" Text="*" />

    //a bunch o others validatiors...

    <asp:ImageButton runat="Server"
    ImageUrl="~/img/anuncie/btn-cadastrar.png" ID="btnEnviar"
    ValidationGroup="Valida" CssClass="btn-cadastrar" />
```

As I said, I need the focus to be on a specific anchor but setting the focus on the `ValidationSummary` or on any field would be nice as well because my fields start far from the top of the page.

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

Different behavior in different browsers:

- IE - Focus is correctly set on fields when clicking on submit (depending on IE version)
- FF - Clicking on submit for the first time moves to the top of the page, second time and on, it set the focus on the fields.
- Chrome - Never works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just switched to [jQuery Validation plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/).